# Unable to copy a binary to a remote Azure VM

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0

I have a Shavlink agent binary from on-prem(VMWare) that has to be copied across to a Azure VM(s).

I used the public VM of the target Azure VM to perform the copy:

```
Copy-Item –Path "C:\ProgramData\LANDESK\Shavlik Protect\Console\DataFiles\STPlatformUpdater.exe" –Destination "D:\Shavlik-Agent\" –ToSession (New-PSSession –ComputerName a.b.c.d)
```

Unfortunately, it gives error as below:

```
New-PSSession : [a.b.c.d] Connecting to remote server a.b.c.d. failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default
authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit
credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to
set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:143
+ ... avlik-Agent\" –ToSession (New-PSSession –ComputerName a.b.c.d.)
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionOpenFailed
Copy-Item : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ToSession'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again
At line:1 char:142
+ ... avlik-Agent\" –ToSession (New-PSSession –ComputerName a.b.c.d+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

On remote machine, I have enabled ports *5985* and *5986* wondering what I need to do to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure your winrm to trust the remote machine, easiest way of doing this is the following:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "a.b.c.d"
```

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management